# Serialization of Rails ActiveRecord object including associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I have a form being submitted for a complex model including many associations. I need to save 2 copies of the object. One that will not be touched and is used only as a reference for what was originally submitted, the other will be edited by my users.

I originally preformed a deep clone of the object and all associations, and then saved both to the database, marking a field for which was the original, and which can be edited. This is becoming too complex however and I would like a simpler solution

I was thinking my best bet would be to serialize the entire object and store it in a single field within the editable object. So my question is: Is it possible to serialize an object, including associations, and store it in a single field?

Should I do this at the model level? or should I just save what was returned from the form in a single field? (ie. application.original_form = params[:application]).

Thanks for your help!
Ryan

EDIT ---

I am attempting this approach:

https://gist.github.com/1298567

I am saving the returned parameters in a serialize field.

Does anyone see any downfall with this? It seems like the simplest approach.

Thanks again!

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone with this approach:

```
 def create
    @app = App.new(params[:app])
    @app.original = params[:app]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @app.save
        format.html { redirect_to(done_path(@app.member.id)) }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
end

#show the original Application
def show
   @app = App.new(App.find(params[:id]).original)
end

#Model

class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :applicant

  serialize :original, Hash

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :applicant
end
```

To me this seems like the simplest approach to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar before, but with only one-level deep associations. E.g. Accounts which had one-or-many Addresses, Contacts, etc..

**You should make sure that your associations of related other models are rather simple, so there are no loops or back-pointers**

It's probably best to save it in a way that is easy to compare later with the current version of the model. You'll need to exclude the 'original' field from the comparison ;-)

During the first saving of the model, I'd do a deep-clone of the model and it's associations and save it to a serialized field 'original' in the main model.

I think I'd use the `serialize` feature of ActiveRecord, e.g.:

```
Class YourMainModel
  ...
  serialize :original   # will serialize this ; make this TEXT field in DB
  ...
end
```

you want to make sure that the data type of the field in the database is text or string, not a binary field!
(that would cause bugs later!)

Then during after_save of the model I would add some code to do something like this:

```
# do this in the after_save - so the validations have run:
main_model_object.original ||= main_model_object.deep_clone  # ||= to do this only once
main_model_object.save(:validate => false) if main_model_object.original_changed?  # save if we added the "copy"
```

There are probably other ways to hook this in, but after_save has the advantage that the validations run.

You'll need to make sure that all associated records are created by the time of the first save, probably you might want to do a "monster form" with nested_forms Gem.

See:

https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable  (Fork for Rails 3)

https://github.com/openminds/deep_cloning (original project)

check out the other Ryan's RailsCasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

hope this helps

---

EDIT:

On a second thought, to limit the size of your database / database dumps, to simplify your schema, and to safe-keep the originals, you might want to store the originals in a separate document store, e.g. you could use MongoDB for that.

If you don't need to access the originals frequently, then storing this in MongoDB as a structured document could be really benefical and it would keep your main application less convoluted.

When you compare records, you'd deep_clone your modified model the same way you did it the first time, then lookup the MongoDB record via the 'id' field of the original record, then compare the two (both are deep clones).

Added benefit of this solution: it would make it harder to accidentially modify the original, as it's not directly attached to the SQL database record. e.g. you couldn't accidentially do `object.original = something`

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried it yet bet it sounds super creepy!
You should use colones of the instances and reference them like this:

```
belongs_to :original_version, :class_name => 'ModelName', :foreign_key => 'original_version_id'
has_one :original_version, :class_name => 'ModelName', :foreign_key => 'original_version_id'
belongs_to :user_version, :class_name => 'ModelName', :foreign_key => 'user_version_id'
has_one :user_version, :class_name => 'ModelName', :foreign_key => 'user_version_id'
```

And yes you put that all in the same model and then you write some methods to check which of these versions the instance is.

Comment: why would you want to make copies of all relations?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar awhile back, and went back and forth many times on these questions. I think I did finally store the editable object-graph serialized, but as XML. In my case users wouldn't really edit except against the original 'template' object, so there was no real reason to re-instantiate the object graph.

But I'm interested in others' solutions.

Is it possible to post a gist? I could maybe give more detailed feedback.